# How do I decouple the actions for each of the item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the color of each button without using unique id in a list of items.

These buttons are defined with separate div elements and I need to change the color of button on click to toggle status.

I managed to do it but it changes the color of 1st element when I click other elements as well. How to decouple and change the color of that respective element. I tried to use $(this) but it is not working.

```
$('.test-toggleswitch-checkbox').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-unchecked').addClass('test-hidden');
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-checked').removeClass('test-hidden');
  } else {
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-checked').addClass('test-hidden');
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-unchecked').removeClass('test-hidden');
  }
});
```

Check the codepen attached here.

https://codepen.io/balamax/pen/eVqbbY

Answer (score 2):

You are using same `id` in every `checkbox` and same `for` value in `label` thats why your first `checkbox` is getting checked all the time

So change the `id` of each `checkbox` and their respective `for` value in `label`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('.test-toggleswitch-checkbox').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-unchecked').addClass('test-hidden');
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-checked').removeClass('test-hidden');
  } else {
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-checked').addClass('test-hidden');
    checkbox.next('.test-toggleswitch-label').find('.test-unchecked').removeClass('test-hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.test-toggleswitch {
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  float: right;
}

.test-toggleswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.test-toggleswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  background-color: #ffb74d;
  border: 1px solid #D38D27;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner.test-checked {
  background-color: #58c459;
  border: 1px solid #4da54e;
  color: #fff;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner:before {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner.test-unchecked:before {
  content: "\e92d";
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Linearicons-dxd';
  float: left;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner.test-checked:before {
  content: "\e92e";
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Linearicons-dxd';
  float: left;
}

.test-cards-list-item-title-actions .test-toggleswitch {
  float: left;
}

.test-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.test-tab-highlight {
  border: 2px #D38D27 solid;
  background: #ffb74d;
  border-bottom-color: #b1dafc;
  color: #333;
}

.test-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20000px !important;
  left: -20000px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch1">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch1"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch2">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch2"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch3">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch3"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch4">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch4"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My bad I missed it and was trying all type of JQuery selectors to pick the correct one from list using different techniques.

Answer (score 0):

As Bhuwan mentioned the problem was in the same id value. But I would like to add that such behavior could be achieved even without JavaScript.

In example below I've moved `input:checkbox` into one level up. And now we can use just simple CSS to highlight selected button:

```
.test-toggleswitch-checkbox:checked + .test-toggleswitch .test-toggleswitch-inner {
    background-color: #58c459;
    border: 1px solid #4da54e;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```css
li{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.test-toggleswitch {
    width: 170px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    float: right;
}

.test-toggleswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.test-toggleswitch-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    background-color: #ffb74d;
    border: 1px solid #D38D27;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 7px 15px;
}

.test-toggleswitch-checkbox:checked + .test-toggleswitch .test-toggleswitch-inner {
    background-color: #58c459;
    border: 1px solid #4da54e;
    color: #fff; 
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner:before {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner.test-unchecked:before {
    content: "\e92d";
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Linearicons-dxd';
    float: left;
}

.test-toggleswitch-inner.test-checked:before {
    content: "\e92e";
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Linearicons-dxd';
    float: left;
}



.test-cards-list-item-title-actions .test-toggleswitch {
    float: left;
}

.test-float-right {
    float: right;
}

.test-tab-highlight {
    border: 2px #D38D27 solid;
    background: #ffb74d;
    border-bottom-color: #b1dafc;
    color: #333;
}

.test-hidden{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20000px !important;
    left: -20000px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch1">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch1"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch2">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch2"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch3">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch3"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="test-cards-list-item-title-actions">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggleswitch" class="test-toggleswitch-checkbox" id="mytoggleswitch4">
      <div class="test-toggleswitch">
        <label class="test-toggleswitch-label" for="mytoggleswitch4"><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-unchecked">SHORTLIST</span><span class="test-toggleswitch-inner test-checked test-hidden">SHORTLISTED</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```